Inference workflow in compile mode using transformers.pipeline()
I am trying to run an inference workflow of a Llama model in compile mode using transformers.pipeline(). I am using the following line of codes to run the inference workflow in compile mode:
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-70B",use_cache=True,device_map='auto')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-70B",use_cache=True,truncation=True,padding="max_length",max_length=64,return_tensors="pt")
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "left"

model = torch.compile(model)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
                     "text-generation",
                       model=model,
                       model_kwargs={"torch_dtype": torch.bfloat16},
                       tokenizer = tokenizer,
                       device_map="auto",
                        )
            
generation_config = {
                        "num_beams":1,
                        "max_new_tokens":32,
                        "do_sample":True,
                        "use_cache":True,
                        }
outputs = pipeline(input_prompt,**generation_config)

It is expected that torch.compile() should compile the model, print some compilation messages but I am not getting any compilation messages.
There is no error message but not getting any compilation messages.
Can you please guide me what might be wrong in code? How can I run an inference workflow of llama model in compile mode using transformers.pipeline()?
I tried to use model = torch.compile(model) and pipeline.model = torch.compile(pipeline.model) but I am not getting any compilation message in any of these two cases.

Use TORCH_LOGS= or TORCH_COMPILE_DEBUG=1 python test.py flag to enable some output logs.
ref: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.compiler_troubleshooting.html
